# Can not compile the code because it is deprecated in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, ns-3

I have a code compiling with ns-3, but I meet some problems when I try to compile them. I think the reason might be some functions are deprecated in C++11. But I do not know how to revise the code.

Here is the code I think should be revised:

```
m_sendBuffer.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        m_sendBuffer.begin(), m_sendBuffer.end(),
        std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(DsrSendBuffer::IsEqual), dst)
    ),
    m_sendBuffer.end()
);
```

Here is the error:

```
../src/dsr/model/dsr-rsendbuff.cc:102:55: error: 'ptr_fun<ns3::dsr::DsrSendBuffEntry, ns3::Ipv4Address, bool>' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                      std::bind (std::ptr_fun (DsrSendBuffer::IsEqual), dst)), m_sendBuffer.end ());

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1115:1: note: 'ptr_fun<ns3::dsr::DsrSendBuffEntry, ns3::Ipv4Address, bool>' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX11 inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:1101:39: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX11'
define _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX11 _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:1090:48: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED'
define _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((deprecated))
```

Comment: @Guillaume +1 (if I could) for the edit!

Comment: it is a warning that is only treated as error because you are compiling with `-Werror` and deprecated means you can still use it now (but maybe not later)

Answer (score 4):

It seem that they use a deprecated API indeed, but you could still compile it by allowing deprecation warning to be treated as warnings. Add this to your compiler options:

```
-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations
```

If you want instead to upgrade the code, you can do this lambda instead:

```
m_sendBuffer.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        m_sendBuffer.begin(), m_sendBuffer.end(),
        [&dst](auto const& buf) { return DsrSendBuffer::IsEqual(buf, dst); }
    ),
    m_sendBuffer.end()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could clone a fresh version of `ns-3`from [ns-3 @ gitlab](https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev).

The use of `std::ptr_fun` and `std::bind2nd` was removed Aug 25, 2019.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I did clone a fresh version of ns-3 and added my own code inside  ⁨bake⁩/source⁩/⁨ns-3.30⁩/⁨src/my-module. However, some new problems appears:⁩                                                                                                             
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ns3::Application::DoInitialize()", referenced from:
      vtable for ns3::MyApp in my-module.cc.1.o
  "ns3::Application::DoDispose()", referenced from:
      vtable for ns3::MyApp in my-module.cc.1.o

Comment: @yucheng I have no first hand experience with `ns-3` myself, but I assume that you are supposed to first build `ns-3` separately and then let your own code use the resulting libraries/headers.